# Projections in the limit algebra of an increasing sequence of algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{R}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{R}_2 \subseteq \cdots $ be an infinite strictly increasing sequence of von Neumann factors (we can assume type III factors if that's easier) acting on the same Hilbert space.

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the limit von Neumann algebra $( \bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n)''$.

**Is every projection in $\mathcal{R}$ necessarily the strong-operator limit of an increasing sequence of projections in $\bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n$?**

I believe that $\mathcal{R}$ is just the strong-operator closure of $\bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n$ [although we can't say, as I originally did, that the latter is a C*-algebra -- see comment below].

Assuming that, I believe the existence of polar decompositions in $\bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n$ entails that every self-adjoint operator in $\mathcal{R}$ is a strong-operator limit of a sequence $T_1, T_2, \ldots$ of self-adjoint operators in $\bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n$. [Edit: I now think this holds only if the algebras are acting on a separable $H$. Go ahead and assume that.]

But this would not by itself give a positive answer to the question since in general there are sequences of self-adjoint operators that are *not* projections, whose limits are projections.

Any suggestions appreciated -- I am not seeing how to proceed. It might help to note that if the answer were positive, then every projection in $\mathcal{R}$ would also be the limit of a *decreasing* sequence of projections in $\bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n$, since if the increasing $T_1, T_2, \ldots$ converge to $(1-T)$, then the decreasing $(1-T_1), (1-T_2), \ldots$ converge to $T$.

Comment: It is not true that the union is already a C$^*$-algebra. The canonical example would be  $\mathcal R_n=M_{2^n}(\mathbb C)$, organized as the increasing union that generates $UHF(2^\infty)$ (and this algebra has operators with spectrum $[0,1]$, while every matrix has discrete spectrum). Regarding your question, achieving all projections as monotone limits sounds like too much to ask (look at Pedersen's up-down lemma, for instance); but I don't have an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I forgot that C* algebras must be norm-closed -- I will make a correction. Follow up on your suggestion I found some discussions on Math Overflow that look relevant, notably https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103306/strong-monotone-limits-and-dense-subalgebras-of-von-neumann-algebras-again . It does seem likely that the answer to my question is negative in general, but it will help my understanding to think through some cases where it's true and where it's false. Will update if I find any that are instructive.